# I need help choosing/creating partitions for elementary os installation

Tags: system-installation, boot

I'm re-installing elementary os as my primary os on my laptop. It has a 500GB SSD and 16 GB RAM.

I installed elementary os 7 in June and am now re-installing because I ran into problems regarding space on the boot partition/drive? Something like that, the system couldn't run updates anymore. Now I'm wanting to do the partitions better, but I've never done that before and honestly don't really know what any of it means. Could anyone help me out me a quick tutorial or direct me to one?

This is where I stand:
[image: current partitions: 276MB fat32; 1GB ext4; 511GB luks]

Thanks in advance!